# Questions about node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web

I've been trying to do some research on node.js and Mongodb and have a few things that need clarifying.

I'm trying to query Mongodb from the web and want to use JavaScript because I'm familiar with the language, plus it makes sense because that's what Mongodb uses in the command line interface.

It seems that I'll have to use node.js to query mongo from the web, but what I can't find info on is a way to tell my node.js server what I want to query, from the web.

If someone can point me in the proper direction ( reading material, how to, examples) that would be awesome.

Comment: Why does your server application not know what to query from the database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info

Answer (score 1):

Here's some articles I used...

http://css.dzone.com/articles/nodejs-and-mongodb-beginner%E2%80%99s-0
http://srirangan.net/2012-02-node-js-and-mongodb-getting-started-with-mongojs
http://mattkopala.com/blog/2012/02/12/getting-started-with-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

I found [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to be the best Node.js MongoDB library (the creator of Mongoose actually now works for 10gen, the company behind MongoDB).

Besides a lot of good examples on the official Mongoose website, you can find lots of other resources:

- http://pixelhandler.com/blog/2012/02/09/develop-a-restful-api-using-node-js-with-express-and-mongoose/
- http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/
- http://dailyjs.com/web-app.html (how to build an app from the start, multiple lessons)

One of the most important things I like about Node.js and MongoDB (Mongoose in my case) is that you are writing the query commands sometimes exactly like you write them in the MongoDB shell.

P.S. Last but not least, checkout the videos from 10gen related to Node.js and MongoDB, there are lots of them (and people using Node with Mongo in production): http://www.10gen.com/presentations#programming_lang__javascript_nodejs